# "_" character and variable conflict in filename, save an image

Tags: php, image, gd

What I'm trying to do is save few images (3) using this function:

```
function save($filename, $image_type = IMAGETYPE_PNG, $compression = 7, $permissions = null){
  if($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
    imagejpeg($this->image, $filename, $compression);
  else if($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF)
    imagegif($this->image, $filename);
  else if($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG)
    imagepng($this->image, $filename);
  if($permissions != null)
    chmod($filename, $permissions);
}
```

But when I save my images under names `images/".$user_id."_32x32.png`, `images/".$user_id."_64x64.png` and `images/".$user_id."_128x128.png`
I get only one of them saved

I tried to change to `"images/".$user_id.".32x32.png"` instead of `images/".$user_id."_32x32.png`
They got all saved

If I save only one of them as `images/".$user_id."_32x32.png` it doesn't save, so it's this character `"_"`  the problem? Why?

**PS.** `$user_id` is an integer

**EDIT**
Tried without any var `images/_32x32.png`, saved all 3 images...
All code here: http://pastebin.com/35Wasb0h

Comment: Can you show how you are calling your function exactly (including building and `var_dump()`'ing the file-names)?

Comment: You need to show how you're creating the filenames and calling the function.  It's probably an error there.

Comment: @jeroen http://pastebin.com/35Wasb0h Everything

Comment: @BarryDevSF http://pastebin.com/35Wasb0h

Comment: How about just how you are building your strings and a `var_dump()` of them?

Comment: @jeroeb Already dumped them, all normal

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"images/{$user_id}_32x32.png"
```

Comment: Same thing, done this for all the 3 images only the first gets saved.